# Convert List<Class> into String JAVAI

Tags: java, string, list

I've a List of values, which is

```
List<Test> myList;

public class Test {
    String type;
    String value;
}
```

When I debug the List Value looks like

```
Test(type=6140, value=2017)
Test(type=6144, value=2017)
```

I want to convert this into a string,

So I tried with like

```
List<Test> myList;

StringBuilder abc = new StringBuilder();
for(Object a: myList){
    abc.append(String.valueOf(a));
}
```

But the result will be like

```
Test(type=6140, value=2017)Test(type=6144, value=2017)
```

But I want to convert the value as

```
[{"type":6140,"value":"2017"},{"type":6144,"value":"2017"}]
```

Comment: You want a JSON array. Use some library like Jackson, it would be simpler

Comment: Do you only want this representation for debugging?

Comment: @daniu No for storing also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using GSON
After including the library this task could be as simple as 
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(myList)

Answer (score 2):

You could either overwrite the ToString() function in your class 'Test' or serialize the objects with JSON. JSON will give you an other but similar output than wanted.
So overwriting the function ToString() will fit your needs more.

Answer (score 0):

if you override the toString method in class Test then the output will be as per your expection.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" +
            "type=" + type +
            ", value=" + value +
            '}';
}
```

**output:**

[{"type":6140,"value":"2017"},{"type":6144,"value":"2017"}]

---